# Appium Setting issue

Tags: appium

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more 
details. 

Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the 
command.

Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 
'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium- 
uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.17.4.apk'. Original 
error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
com/android/apksigner/ApkSignerTool has been compiled by a more recent 
version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the 
Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This Could be when the appium is not shutting down smoothly,
I have just restarted my Pc and then did not see such error.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it.The version of build tool folder in your directory:'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools' do not beyond the build tool version of your application using.It may be a bug of APPIUM.